# Unable to use Copy-PnP File to copy site pages across sharepoint online sites

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I tried using all the below examples for copying my site pages across different SharePoint sites but always keep getting the below error: Can someone give correct syntax, please?

***Copy-PnPFile : Cannot contact site at the specified URL***

```
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl SitePages/Home.aspx -TargetUrl "/sites/destination/SitePages"
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl SitePages -TargetUrl "/sites/destination/SitePages"
Copy-PnPFile -SourceUrl /sites/sourcesite/SitePages/Home.aspx -TargetUrl "/sites/destination/SitePages"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did the TargetUrl sitr is valid ? "/sites/destination" should be existed in your Tenant.

I tested the PowerShell command below, it will pop up a confirm dialogue like this if the target url is correct:

[image]

Comment: Yes. my destination site is already existing. I tried with different pages as well and all give the same error that the command is unable to contact the site at the specified URL which is the source url.  May i know which version of powershell are you using?  Also i see someone asking for same error as mine at the link below but could not see any answers.       https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Sites-Core/issues/2487

Comment: I'm using the PnP.PowerShell from here : https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PnP.PowerShell/1.3.19-nightly

Comment: I think it makes sense  Mine was SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline 3.25.2009.1  version.  I had PnP.Powershell installed on a different box and it works there. Not sure why it is not working with old version.

Comment: Great. you could use the new PnP.PowerShell as the old version has been archived. You could accept the answer if it's working now :)

Comment: @NethiSwapna, please accept as answer so that it could be also helpful to the others in the forum who have the similiar question :)